# C#: Getting google maps square chunk image and corner coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, image, api, google-maps

I need to get Image object from Google Maps, centered to a given address, and get its corners coordinates. How to achieve this in C#? Thanks in advance for replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the terms of service you can not get the chunk images from Google maps, You can use the API to get a image of what you want, [see the documentation on how to request a specific address](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html#Addresses), it is simply a set of url encoded parameters

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false
```